# streambuf, ostream, ostreambuf, istream, istreambuf and associated iterators

Tags: c++, stl, stream, iterator, buffer

I guess somebody had to ask these questions, so please bear with me.

Let's consider the following beasts:

- ostream
- istream
- iostream
- streambuf
- <strike>string</strike> - Following Benjamin's observation, this one does not belong here.
- stringbuf

and the following iterators:

- ostream_iterator
- ostreambuf_iterator
- istream_iterator
- istreambuf_iterator

**Questions:**

Why isn't there any `iostream_iterator`, `streambuf_iterator`, <strike>`string_iterator`</strike> (std::string::iterator and std::string::const_iterator do exist) or `stringbuf_iterator`?

Why don't the 4 iterators listed above have a const version like `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`?

How are we supposed to iterate over any of those beasts if they don't provide the begin() and end() methods? What is the purpose of the above 4 iterators?

N00b question: Where can I find a good reference that details the logic behind these classes and, also, some decent examples on how to use them?

Hopefully, someone with experience will provide a good answer for the above questions.

---

PS: Real life situation:

```
void writeToStream(std::ostream &out);
int main ()
{
    std::ostringstream byteStream;
    writeToStream(byteStream);
    std::string byteString = byteStream.str();

    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < byteString.size(); ++i)
    {
        //do something with each byteString[i]
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My guess is that I could have used `ostream` and iterate over its elements by using an iterator just like for `std::vector`, instead of using `ostringstream` and the `str()` method to convert it to a `string`, but I couldn't find any information regarding this.

Comment: keep in mind that streams are streams, not containers (which means in most cases that you can not go back and/or will destroy the data you read)

Comment: @PasmaHH: OK, that is one good point. Thanks! :) I still expect a detailed explanation for the questions, though.

Comment: Why have you grouped `string` in there? There is `string::iterator`, and `string::const_iterator`, and `string::begin()` and `string::end()`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Oups... My bad. You're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why isn't there any:
>   * iostream_iterator
>   * streambuf_iterator

Don't know. Probably because the semantics would be hard to define when doing both input and output. What do you expect to happen when you go forward and then backwards in a stream with an iterator?

> - string_iterator
> - stringbuf_iterator?

These are easily covered by the existing iterators:

```
std::string                  line; // load line.
std::stringstream            linestream(line);
std::istream_iterator<int>   lineIterator(linestream);
```

> Why don't the 4 iterators listed above have a const version like std::vector::const_iterator?

Because when you iterate across a stream the state of the stream is changing.

> How are we supposed to iterate over any of those beasts if they don't provide the begin() and end() methods? What is the purpose of the above 4 iterators?

Because a stream is usually one direction. You don't iterate from the beginning but rather iterate from the current position in the stream to the end. So you just declare an iterator specifying the stream. The iterator starts at the current position and moves towards the end. You can declare an end of stream iterator by just not spcifying the stream.

```
 std::istream_iterator<int>   loop(std::cin);
 for(;loop != std::istream_iterator<int>(); ++loop)
 {
     std::cout << *loop;
 }
```

> N00b question: Where can I find a good reference that details the logic behind these classes and, also, some decent examples on how to use them?

Here is a good place.
Do a search for "C++ istream_iterator" you will get a lot of hits.

> Hopefully, someone with experience will provide a good answer for the above questions.

Hopefully.

Comment: Well, thank you for the good answer and for taking the time to provide it. In your example code, why do you compare `loop` with `std::istream_iterator<int>()`?

Comment: Because: `std::istream_iterator<int>()` is an iterator that marks the end of stream equivalent of `end()` on a container. When you increment loop past the end of the stream it will compare equal to an object created like this.

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't there any iostream_iterator, streambuf_iterator or
>   stringbuf_iterator?

I don't know.  Though I would guess that it's simply because they would be more complicated, and there isn't enough demand for them.

> Why don't the 4 iterators listed above have a const version like
>   `std::vector<T>::const_iterator`?

A const input iterator would be rather redundant, you can only read from them anyway, not write to them.  A const output iterator would be pointless, as that would destroy it's only purpose, which is to output.

> How are we supposed to iterate over any of those beasts if they don't
>   provide the begin() and end() methods? What is the purpose of the
>   above 4 iterators?

By creating the iterators with their respective constructors, e.g.

```
std::istream_iterator<int> in_begin(std::cin), in_end;
std::ostream_iterator<int> out_begin(std::cout, "\n");
std::copy(in_begin, in_end, out_begin);
```

Note that the end iterator for `istream_iterator` is created by simply passing no arguments to its constructor, and that there is no equivalent to an `end()` for an output iterator.

Comment: The iterators are input/output qualified because you use them either as a source or as a destination, not both, as it's assumed they consume or generate a stream that you can't just go back to a previous position.

Comment: Thanks for the `std::copy` usage example, Benjamin. Your comments were very useful, but I decided to accept Loki's answer, because it contains some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Those stream iterators exist to do the trick of writing to/reading from a stream directly from/to a container using standard algorithms. So instead of writing

```
for (vector<int>::iterator i=v.begin(); i!=v.end(); ++i)
    cout << *i <<"\n";
```

you can just use std::copy:

```
copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator(cout, "\n"));
```

For a reference, check something like [this](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibref/2-8.html), or [TC++PL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C%2B%2B_Programming_Language). IMHO they are a neat trick, but don't really help much, as you have little control over the input/output.

Comment: What is the TC++PL? "Tompkins County Public Library"?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to linkify it. It's Stroustrup's book.

Comment: OK. Thanks! And +1 for the nice Apache documentation.